# Data Operations over two dataframes using time constraint in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes:-

```
df1:-

PID DATE       Time   Amount
xy1 01/10/2019  8:37    100
xy1 01/10/2019  12:30   100
xy2 01/10/2019  5:01    100
xy3 01/10/2019  23:57   100
```

```
df2
PID DATE    Time    Amount  Code
xy1 01/10/2019  8:00    4   38
xy1 01/10/2019  8:05    50  38
xy1 01/10/2019  8:20    60  39
xy1 01/10/2019  8:45    80  39
xy2 01/10/2019  1:02    100 39
xy2 01/10/2019  3:05    100 38
xy2 01/10/2019  5:10    90  38
```

I want to get the count of `df1['PID']` depending on the date&time in df1&df2. i.e How many times `df1['PID'][0]` is in df2 before the `df1['Date', 'Time']` as compared to df2 date time. Really appreciate the help.
Output shall be like this:-

```
PID Before_df1time_38   Before_df1time_39   Total   After_df1time_38    After_df1time_39
xy1        2               1                  3            0                1
```